# Why do I see connection timeouts every 2 minutes to my Redis instance?

Tags: node.js, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm running a `cache.t2.micro` Redis instance on AWS Elasticache. I'm just using the 3.2 default parameters at the moment.

I'm connecting using the node [`redis` module](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) to connect, just for the purposes of having a pub/sub system.

For some reason, every 2 minutes and 11 seconds, I see

```
2017-07-27-14:16:05 0|server   | Error: Redis connection to my-redis-instance:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT my-redis-ip:6379
2017-07-27-14:16:05 0|server   |     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1016:11)
2017-07-27-14:16:05 0|server   |     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1039:20)
```

I've looked at the Redis parameters and the `timeout` is set to 0.

What could be killing this connection? I'm sure it's a configuration setting somewhere... but what?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the issue was that the Redis server was not in an appropriate security group. It just takes roughly 2m for the initial connection attempt to fail!